# can i combine these two statements?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to following all the links contained in a certain class
(`f_foto`) in the DOM, follow them and then examine the results.  I
could use `XMLHttp.Request` but the site returns only HTTP text, not XML
(or at least `.responseXML` is null).  Rather than scrape the string, I
am trying to stick with examining the DOM resulting from the response
text so I open a new window with the src from the link found in the
`f_foto` class.  The window opens ok, but after that I can't access the
new window.  Note that it is not necessary to use a new window but I
can't figure out how to convert a text file to a DOM any other way.

In the following code the window opens a new window but testing the
theory in the next statement, which changes the background color to
black, an error is returned "cannot set property 'bgcolor' of
undefined."  Here it doesn't matter what I use to manipulate
detailWindow - it's always undefined.  Based on the research I did
this must have to do with the fact that this script is located in the
parent page and not in the opened page.  So how do I get control over
the newly opened window?  What I would like is to have the result of

```
document.getElementById("tab_content").

var detailWin;
for (var i = 0; i<searchResult.length; ++i)
{
       detailWin=window.open(profileLinks[i], "Detail Window",
               "width=700, height=650, resizable=1, toolbar=0, location=0,
status=0, menubar=0, directories=0, scrollbars=yes, top=0, left=0");
       detailWin.bgColor="black"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding your question, but it sound like you're saying that all you need this for is converting a bunch of arbitrary html pages specified by URLs into DOM that you can manipulate all in one place; you don't actually need to show a popup window to the user.

If my understanding is correct, you could probably use jQuery's load function.

If you've got a random div on your page (probably set it to display:none), you can use that to load the content of a url into that div, and then you can just manipulate whatever you want to in the DOM under that div as if that content was always there.

```
<div id='someRandomDiv'></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    loadIsDone = function() {
        //do stuff with document.getElementById('someRandomDiv').childNodes;
    };

    $('#someRandomDiv').load('http://www.url.com', loadIsDone);
</script>
```

Comment: yes, exactly! i've been thinking exactly that but i don't know how to do it.  i get the idea you can create a div in an loaded page and hide it and put whatever you want there.  but the details of how to do that are a big learning curve on top of learning how to handle DOM elements which i understand most of you guys think is pretty elemental in the first place. (!!:)) yucky pun!  can you suggest some code snippets that would do that?  this is a chrome extension btw.  is jQuery available to a chrome extension?

Comment: jQuery is a javascript library. You can either download it from jQuery.com and host it from your site, just add a script tag that points to a version google hosts. Like: <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.6.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> or: <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> As far as hooking it into a chrome extension, I'm not really sure - I had assumed this was just a web page.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your new window complies with [Same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript), you should be able to access the popup like normal.  Basically what this means is the popup must be on the same protocol and host.

The return value of `window.open` is the `window` object of the popup, so to make your code work, you would need to set the `bgColor` property on the window's `document`.

```
document.getElementById("tab_content").

var detailWin;
for (var i = 0; i<searchResult.length; ++i)
{
       detailWin=window.open(profileLinks[i], "Detail Window",
               "width=700, height=650, resizable=1, toolbar=0, location=0,
status=0, menubar=0, directories=0, scrollbars=yes, top=0, left=0");
       detailWin.document.bgColor="black"
}
```

Comment: That didn't help.  Now it returns an error - "Uncaught TypeError" Cannot read property 'document' of undefined"

Comment: Anything that references detailWin returns undefined but the window does open with the desired html displayed each time the loop is repeated.